# Regex to check a simple number between [0-6]

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var number = '731231';

var myRegex = /[0-6]/; 

console.log(myRegex.test(number));
```

Can anyone explain this ?

IMO the regex written as [0-6] will only check for numbers between 0 and 6 but in the above case the value as large as 731231 is also evaluated to be true

Comment: It tests whether a character of your string matches [0-6] `3` surely does.

Comment: `console.log(number.match(myRegex));` returns `3` as the first number it matches.

Comment: As a side note - this isn't a good use for regex.

Comment: @Emissary why are you saying so ?

Comment: Regex is notably slower (reasons already documented all over SO), you may argue that the difference can be negligible but it's just lazy.  Regex is for parsing **strings** character by character, you are dealing with a number (a single entity) - there are specific comparison operators and `Math` logic which are far more flexible and robust when handling numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex matches, when there is *any* such digit present. If you want to match *only* such digits, use

```
/^[0-6]+$/
```

This matches a string with any number of digits from 0-6. If you want a single digit, omit the `+`:

```
/^[0-6]$/
```

Comment: @aelor: Read all about [anchors here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). And if you don't want to allow `11` to match (because it's larger than 6), drop the `+`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants `/^[0-6]+$/.test ("42")` to return `false`. In the means of `+'731231' < 6 && +'731231' > 0;`

Answer (score 2):

Yiu should use

```
  var myRegex = /^[0-6]$/;
```

you're looking for a string that *starts* **^** then **contains one** *0..6 digit* and immediately *ends* **$**

Your implementation `/[0-6]/` is looking for a *0..6 digit* **anywhere** within the string, and that's why *731231* meets this criterium.

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if there is somewhere a number between 0 and 6, which is the case.

```
var number = '731231';

var myRegex = /^[0-6]+$/; 

console.log(myRegex.test(number));
```

**UPDATE**

Though, if you want the string to match a number satisfying the rule `0 >= N <= 6`
This would be what you want

```
var myRegex = /^[0-6]$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is checking to see if one of the following appears in the string:

0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6

and that is true because there is 1, 2 and 3 in there.

If you want to check that the whole string is a number then you could use:

```
var myRegex = /^[0-9]+$/;
```